# Kafka streams - Fetching 4 values from input topic, passing to a function, then sending to output topic aggregating based on key

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In this simple version, I was just taking one input value and aggregating that. Instead, I would like to take 4 values received from the input topic, pass these into a function, and then use the value returned to be aggregated in the output topic based on the key.

Essentially keeping a running total of the values for each key. The 4 inputs are just **Doubles** that are used to calculate a single final figure which is added to the running total.

I'm not quite sure of the syntax for it, does anyone have any ideas?

```
private val streamsBuilder = StreamsBuilder()
    private val trips = streamsBuilder.stream<String, String>(inputTopic)
    private val distance_travelled = trips
        .peek { _, trip -> logger.info(trip) }
        .mapValues { _, trip ->
            objectMapper.readValue(trip, TripClass::class.java)
        }
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(
            { 0L },
            { _, trip, total -> total + trip.amount },
            Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long())
        )
```

Calling the function here does sort of work, but `.aggregate` complains if I try to change the data type from **Long** to **Double**.

```
.aggregate(
            { 0L },
            { _, trip, total -> total + exampleFunction(trip) },
            Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long())
        )
```

**EDIT**
Clarification on the error produced by changing data type from **Serdes.Long** to **Serdes.Double**

```
    Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter VR in 
    
    fun <VR : Any!> aggregate
    (
    initializer: (() → VR!)!,
    aggregator: ((key: String!, value: Transaction!, aggregate: VR!) → VR!)!,
    materialized: Materialized<String!, VR!, KeyValueStore<Bytes!, ByteArray!>!>!
    )
    : KTable<String!, VR!>!
    None of the following substitutions
    
    
    
    (
    (() → Double!)!,
    ((String!, Transaction!, Double!) → Double!)!,
    Materialized<String!, Double!, KeyValueStore<Bytes!, ByteArray!>!>!
    )
    
    
    
    (
    (() → Long!)!,
    ((String!, Transaction!, Long!) → Long!)!,
    Materialized<String!, Long!, KeyValueStore<Bytes!, ByteArray!>!>!
    )
    can be applied to
    
    
    
    (
    () → Long,
    (String!, Transaction!, Double) → Double,
    Materialized<String!, Double!, KeyValueStore<Bytes!, ByteArray!>!>!
    )
```

**Update**

```
distance.aggregate(
    { 0.0 }, // 0.0 for Double initializer, 0L for Long2
    { _, trip, balance:Double -> balance + eh(trip) }, { _, leftAggValue, rightAggValue ->
            leftAggValue + rightAggValue
        },
        Materialized.`as`<String, Double, SessionStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>("stateStoreName")
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(Serdes.Double())
            .withLoggingDisabled())
```

The above produces no error itself but causes an error on this line.

`distance.toStream().to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()))`

There's no error without the window, the change of type causes some sort of issue. Any ideas?
The error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

to(((key: Windowed<String!>!, value: Double!, recordContext: RecordContext!) → String!)!, Produced<Windowed<String!>!, Double!>!)

defined in org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream
to(String!, Produced<Windowed<String!>!, Double!>!)

 defined in org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream
to(TopicNameExtractor<Windowed<String!>!, Double!>!, Produced<Windowed<String!>!, Double!>!)

 defined in org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream
```

Comment: The error seems to say that `total + exampleFunction(trip)` returns `Any` , not `Long`, so what if you cast that addition result?

Comment: It complains that the first **total** type cannot be inferred.

`{ _, trip, total -> (total + distanceFromCoords(trip)).toDouble() },`

Explicitly stating it fixes that error

`{ _, trip, total:Double -> (total + distanceFromCoords(trip)).toDouble() }`

the **None of the following substitutions** error looks unchanged though.

Comment: Based on the question statement, you want a Long, not a Double, since that is your Serde type... Did you change that?

Comment: @OneCricketeer `Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double())`
 Do you mean this line?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread the question. If the aggregation return type is a double, then the initiializer cannot be a Long, so change `0L` to `0.0`, and use `{ _, trip, total:Double ->`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for all the help, that fixed it. One more thing that has come up with windowing if you could spare a minute. Another type error it looks like, I'll update the question.

Comment: If I am reading that correctly, your `outputTopic` is a `Windowed` object, not a String, or a TopicNameExtractor

Comment: @OneCricketeer The outputTopic variable is definitely a string, passing a string directly gives the same error also. Changing it to this
`distance.toStream().to(outputTopic, Produced.with(SessionWindowedSerde(Serdes.String()), Serdes.Double()))` removes the error, although the key now shows up as gibberish in the output topic. Must have the Serdes wrong in some way.